# Read JSON Object key with colon in name

Tags: angularjs, json

I need some guidance on how to access this key of a JSON object using angular 2.

I tried

```
{{news._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].id}}
```

but it tells me that cannot read property '0'

```
[
  {
  "_embedded": {
    "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
        "id": 7240
         }
     ]
    }
  }
 ]
```

In my template:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let news of newsObj">
    {{news._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].id}}
</ion-card>
```

Comment: You mean a colon `:`, not a semicolon `;`

Answer (score 6):

Use `obj['key']` to use such keys.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.obj = [
  {
  "_embedded": {
    "wp:featuredmedia": [
        {
        "id": 7240
         }
     ]
    }
  }
 ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table style='border:1px solid black'>
    <tr ng-repeat="n in obj">
      <td>{{n._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0]['id']}}<td>
      <tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: if i make {{news._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"] | json }}, I have [ { "id":7240 }] but if I want to retrieve the "id" node is not working....

Comment: @kazou i have modified the answer. It is returning `news._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0]['id']`.

Comment: I have tested this {{news._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0]['id']}} but it tells me "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: @kazou In My code snippet,it is working fine. You need to check whether you have ["wp:featuredmedia"] in news._embedded.

Comment: in fact, I retrieve a JSON file from a website and in some cases ["wp:featuredmedia"] don't exist.

Comment: @kazou In that case you can check like `{{news._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"] && news._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0]['id'][0]['id']}}` to ensure the availability of `news._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"]`